# View Google Books in Android mobiles?

Tags: ebooks

Is it possible to see Sample Preview or Full Google Books, in Android devices?

Do we have an app for that?

I have `Android 4.2` in my *Micromax Ninja A89*.

Small parts of all books are viewable in Google Books, they call it "(Sample) Preview", I want to be able to see this preview in Android, even if I am not able to download, I want to view it with an active internet connection in my mobile.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Google-made app with almost exactly that name, that does let you read Google Books on your Android device, [Google Play Books](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books). I'm pretty sure that should do what you want.

Comment: Google play books is to read the full books that you have purchased on Google Play and free samples of the books available in Google Play. It does not supports Google Books.

Comment: @user221287 ahh so you're specifically after the ones in Google Books that specify "No eBook available", and don't have a PDF download option available for them? I'm pretty sure that if they don't show up in when you use the advanced search tips here http://support.google.com/books/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44664 then you can't download them to read on your device. Downloadable books will be in PDF format, and can be read by using one of the [PDF reader apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pdf+reader&c=apps) available.

Comment: Small parts of all books are view-able in Google Books, they call it "(Sample) Preview", I want to be able to see this preview in android, even if I am not able to download, I want to view it with an active internet connection in my mobile.